# Embedding kotlin-compiler-embeddable into a Java EE App leads to CDI related deployment error

Tags: jakarta-ee, kotlin, cdi, payara

I am trying to add the capability to run kotlin script (kts) in a Java EE (and therefore CDI) application.

After adding the dependency to `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.31`, deployment of the war fails with the following message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The lifecycle method [initialize]
>   must not have more than one parameter. Related annotation information:
>   annotation [@javax.annotation.PostConstruct()] on annotated element
>   [public void
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.AbstractJavaClassFinder.initialize(org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.BindingTrace,org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.KotlinCodeAnalyzer)]
>   of type [METHOD]

Looking at `AbstractJavaClassFinder#initialize` from the added dependency I can see it is in fact annotated with `@javax.annotation.PostConstruct` and it has two parameters.

How do I solve this problem?

Is it a bug? JSR-250 Common Annotations states in section 2.5 `javax.annotation.PostConstruct` "The method MUST NOT have any parameters.".

As a workaround: Is there a way to tell my cdi container to ignore this annotation and would that have any other impact?

Comment: created an issue in kotlin issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32275